# Adding binomial distributions?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, standard-deviation

I'm not sure how to solve this problem:

> Let X and Y be iid Binomial distributions with n=32 and p=.5. Let Z= X
>   +Y. Find the standard deviation of Z.

Comment: https://www.stat.wisc.edu/courses/st311-rich/convol.pdf

Comment: Unless you assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent, there is no unique answer.  Assuming independence, what do you know about how expectations of sums are related to the expectations of their component variables?

Comment: @whuber It says "iid".

Comment: Title is wrong. You're not adding the distribution functions, you're looking at a distribution of a sum of random variables (i.e. you're adding random variables not their distributions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $X$ and $Y$ are $iid$ Binomial variates with parameters $n=32$ and $p=0.5$. By the additive property of the binomial distribution, the random variable $Z = X + Y\sim Bin(32+32, 0.5)$. Then, $E(Z)=64\times 0.5 = 32$ and $Var(Z) = 64\times 0.5 \times 0.5$. Hence, $SD(Z)= \sqrt(Var(Z))$.

It can also be obtained, from the definitions of expectation and variance, directly.

By definition, $E(Z)=E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$.

$Var(Z)=Var(X) + Var(Y)$, since $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

$SD(X) = \sqrt(var(Z))= \sqrt(Var(X)+Var(Y))$

Comment: +1.  Note that the additive property of the Binomial is not needed: the results about expectation and variance, appropriately restated, are true of *any* two independent distributions.

Comment: @whuber Yes. Actually, the correct way in the given context.